# Which of these is the best way to get a list item collection?

Tags: splistitem, performance, splist, spquery

Performance-wise which of these methods is the best way to get a list item collection, and why?

```
SPList list = web.getlist("listurl");
SPListItemCollection items = list.getItems(query);
foreach(SPListItem item in items)
{
 ......
}
```

or

```
foreach(SPListItem item in web.getlist("listurl").getItems(query))
{
   ....
}
```

Comment: There is no real difference in what you are doing. The first one has a better readability though.

Comment: wouldnot it will query list and try to get items again and again in second one?

Comment: Maybee if it was javascript or something. But not in C#. But I would write is as in the first example anyway, for the readability

Comment: I can see difference, first one is 00:00:01.2412859 whereas second one is 00:00:01.234146 on a demo list

Comment: Seriously, that time different is probable just for binding the extra variable names. It's like what 0.009s difference there?

Comment: I bet it will not, since the extra milliseconds most probably is due to the variable binding, or some external factor. For more items, you will not do more variable bindings. And anyway, if it would do the list query every iteration, the gap would be much wider than a couple of milliseconds

Comment: it will not make difference to use first one or second. because in foreach loop it will get items first and then iterate through it. it's not make sense if getItems run every time, if it's do, then it will always return the first item. i think in this case you have to focus on "query" itself, for example set it's RowLimit and ViewFields, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(SPListItem item in web.getlist("listurl").getItems(query))
{
   ....
}
```

This is wrong approach:

The reason is SPListItemCollection is created for each cycle of the foreach. Ex: 100 ListItem fetched from query each time SPListItemCollection object created from web. It will create you best performance issue. To avoid that you should define the object before use it in the foreach.

Comment: This is not javascript, the collection will not be returned everytime, it will be cached.